# Change a makefile to produce a dll instead of an exe

Tags: dll, makefile, mingw

I need to compile exe program as dll. I've added DllMain to main.c and _declspec(dllexport) before main function. To compile the program I use MinGW Shell and Makefile. What do I need to change in the Makefile to build a dll instead of an exe?

Comment: I don't think it has a lot to do with `make`. anyway, [this link](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/sampleDLL) might help

Comment: Do you know how to build the dll from the command line, without Make?

Comment: I have to use make, makefile contains a lot of settings and I do not know what they are doing, but without them the project can not be compiled. Taylor Flores, unfortunately your example does not contain information about makefile